# Destructuring In JavaScript and Initialization

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, destructuring

How does initialization work in JavaScript?  I am getting an error on the below code saying cannot access `obj` before initialization.

```js
let a = 7;
let b = 10;

const obj = { a:23, b:35, c:70 }
({a, b} = obj);
console.log(a, b);
```

Comment: const {a, b} = obj;

Comment: @Mellet - OP seems to want to update existing variables.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, yes. Sorry ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're relying on Automatic Semicolon Insertion and no automatic semicolon is added after the `const obj...` line. Without one, that line and the following one are treated as one expression which does indeed try to access `obj` before it's initialized:

```
const obj = { a:23, b:35, c:70 }({a, b} = obj);
```

To the parser, that looks like a function call. If you weren't trying to access `obj` in what the parser thinks is an arguments list, it would have failed when it got to the point of calling the object, since the object isn't callable.

You need an explicit semicolon to separate the statements:

```js
let a = 7;
let b = 10;

const obj = { a:23, b:35, c:70 }; // <==== Here
({a, b} = obj);
console.log(a, b);
```

Looking at your code, you probably just forgot this one since you include other ones. But if you're going to rely on ASI, make sure you prefix every line starting with `(`, `[`, or `` ` `` with a `;` to prevent that line from continuing the previous expression.

Comment: T.J. Crowder Thanks a lot it worked. I was relying on ASI so i don't know how it missed it.

Answer (score 2):

Put semicolon after the `}`

```js
let a = 7;
let b = 10;

const obj = { a:23, b:35, c:70 };
({a, b} = obj);
console.log(a, b);
```